# Bug in editing questions when reviewing a queue

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When I view the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17111594#) in the review queue and click "Edit", it takes me to the top of the page, and does nothing.  However, when I open it up as a regular page, then clicking "Edit" gives the following error:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

Even if this edit goes through by the time you view this, this should be a replicatable bug.